# Cert-Manager is not issuing any certificates Google Cloud Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, https, cert-manager

I am struggling to get cert-manager to issue certificates from let's encrypt which I can use with my ingress in Google Cloud Kubernetes.

I have a cluster running with a deployment, service and ingress in the default namespace. I also registered a domain at namecheap and added an A record to the IP address from my ingress. Now I can access the website with http and everything is fine. Now I want to move to https and things do not work.

I have installed cert-manager:

```
kubectl create namespace cert-manager
kubectl apply --validate=false -f https://github.com/jetstack/cert-manager/releases/download/v0.13.1/cert-manager.yaml
```

I verified that cert-manager is running:

```
kubectl get pods --namespace cert-manager
NAME                                       READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
cert-manager-5655447474-kw9k7              1/1     Running   0          99m
cert-manager-cainjector-59c9dfd4f7-fjzbf   1/1     Running   0          99m
cert-manager-webhook-865b8fb666-7kmx2      1/1     Running   0          99m
```

Now I created a ClusterIssuer `kubectl apply -f letsencrypt-prod.yaml` in the default namespace:

```
apiVersion: certmanager.k8s.io/v1alpha1
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt-prod
spec:
  acme:
    server: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    email: 'my@email.com'
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: letsencrypt-prod
    http01: {}
```

And added a certificate with `kubectl apply -f certificate.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: certmanager.k8s.io/v1alpha1
kind: Certificate
metadata:
  name: my-certs
spec:
  secretName: my-certs
  issuerRef:
    name: letsencrypt-prod
    kind: ClusterIssuer
  commonName: "www.mydomain.de"
  dnsNames:
  - "www.mydomain.de"
  acme:
    config:
    - dns01:
        provider: cloud-dns
      domains:
      - "www.mydomain.de"
```

This is my ingress:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: "my-ip"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: www.mydomain.de
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: my-service
          servicePort: 80
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - www.mydomain.de
    secretName: my-certs
```

Now when I run `kubectl describe certificate my-certs` there are no events:

```
kubectl describe certificate my-certs
Name:         my-certs
Namespace:    default
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:
                {"apiVersion":"certmanager.k8s.io/v1alpha1","kind":"Certificate","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"my-certs","namespace":"default"},"sp...
API Version:  certmanager.k8s.io/v1alpha1
Kind:         Certificate
Metadata:
  Creation Timestamp:  2020-02-23T13:30:15Z
  Generation:          1
  Resource Version:    787204
  Self Link:           /apis/certmanager.k8s.io/v1alpha1/namespaces/default/certificates/my-certs
  UID:                 a027a698-5640-11ea-bce8-42010a9c00dc
Spec:
  Acme:
    Config:
      Dns 01:
        Provider:  cloud-dns
      Domains:
        www.mydomain.de
  Common Name:  www.mydomain.de
  Dns Names:
    www.mydomain.de
  Issuer Ref:
    Kind:       ClusterIssuer
    Name:       letsencrypt-prod
  Secret Name:  my-certs
Events:         <none>
```

And in Google Cloud Console I see the message "Could not find TLS certificates. Continuing setup for the load balancer to serve HTTP" for the ingress.

What is wrong here or what am I missing?

Comment: post logs from cert manager and webhook pod. What ingress controller are you using? Post logs from ingress controller pod

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating the certificate resource manually you can add below annotation to the ingress resource:

```
cert-manager.io/issuer: "letsencrypt-prod"
```

Cert-manager will read the annotation and use them to create a certificate.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: "my-ip"
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: "letsencrypt-prod"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: www.mydomain.de
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: my-service
          servicePort: 80
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - www.mydomain.de
    secretName: my-certs
```

After this check if a secret and certificate with name my-certs got created or not.

Also check the related [issue](https://github.com/jetstack/cert-manager/issues/1343)

Comment: Thanks. Shouldn't this be: `cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: "letsencrypt-prod"`? As I used a ClusterIssuer instead of an Issuer?

Comment: Yes you are right...I missed that.edited the answer.

Comment: The certificate is now successfully created, but there is still an error: error running load balancer syncing routine: loadbalancer does not exist: Cert creation failures - k8s-ssl-5c596d7308e70816-e3b0c44298fc1c14--9980a040e40e8402 Error:googleapi: Error 400: Invalid value for field 'resource.certificate': ''. A certificate must be specified for SSL certificate creation., invalid

Comment: where is the error ? in cert manager pod? Is this error different than previous one?

Comment: Are you using GCE ingress or some other? Did you check the secret got created or not? Can you describe the secret and see if it has non empty tls and key

Comment: Yes, GCE Ingress

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208361/discussion-between-arghya-sadhu-and-needrhelp).

Comment: To check certificates, you should use `kubectl get certificate.cert-manager.io -A`. In my (very specific) case, the issue was that Cloudflare token was missing Zone List permission.

Comment: @Gajus could you please add more information about what does that means: "Cloudflare token was missing Zone List permission". What find of Cloudflare token? And what is Zone List permission? I'm new to Cloudflare and have hard times setting up SSL into my kinaba inside k8s